# How to create dependency on 2 different java script files, something similar to depends-on method in TestNG?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have two JS files with test methods, File1 and File2. File2.js should be executed only if the File1.js has passed all the execution. I am currently using Javascript with mocha framework and WDIO

Answer (score 0):

Generally dependencies between tests in this fashion aren't desirable for a few reasons:

- File2 becomes more complex to debug insolation due to the need of running File1 first.
- You can't run your tests in parallel to speed up execution.
- Testing File2 functionality is blocked if File1 fails.

In a hypothetical basic example let's say File1 tests user account creation and File2 tests posting a message.

One way to remove the dependency is to have a separate pre-seeded account (perhaps created via apis or database script) that File2 uses to test the posting feature. That means you can still test posting if the user account creation fails (and those can both run at once).

So if possible I'd advise thinking if there are ways you can avoid the dependency.

If there is no way around it could you potentially use a before block check in File2 that asserts things are in the state you expect, otherwise it will fail the before and therefore File2 checks are skipped?

```js
before(`Did File 1 Run Successfully`, () => {
  expect(isMyFile1DataInPlace()).toBe(true)
})
```